# Django. TestCase login_required

Tags: python, django, login-required

This is my code:

```
from django.test import TestCase
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class BetsTest(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        user = User.objects.create_user('test', 'test', 'test')
        user.save()
        self.client.login(username='test', password='test')

    def test_details(self):
        response = self.client.post('/bets/makebet/5', {'points' : '24'})
        self.failUnlessEqual(response.status_code, 200)
```

And my view has decorator @login_required.. And no matter what I am doing my response is status: 301....

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you're posting something, it's probably gonna redirect you to a success page right? That's not a 200 code.

Set `follow=True` on your `post` call and it should work fine.

```
response = self.client.post('/bets/makebet/5', {'points' : '24'}, follow=True)
```

You can also access the redirects if you do this with `response.redirect_chain`

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/tools/

Comment: No.. only redirect comes from @login_required decorator.. Otherwise it will return return render_to_response('bets/getreward.html', {'message' : message}, context_instance=RequestContext(request)).. but with another message.